# wordpress web server WAN/LAN connection error

Tags: wordpress, raspberry-pi

i made web server for WordPress on raspberry pi (low cost linux single board computer). In local network everything is ok. i bought static ip from my ISP and i forwarded 80 port of raspberry to global network. while trying to connect WordPress by global ip from external network (e.g. smartphone with 4G) pages are too slow(images not shown and theme is basic).

[image: screenshot of website]

To solve that i change wordpress site url&wordpress url from local ip to global ip. at this time i can connect from external network with global ip too fast, but i cannot connect it by desktop computer which is on local network(browser going to router(huawei HG658)main page when global ip was entered) so that i can’t use dashboard, write posts anything else. How can i solve this ?

Comment: What is your network speed from any internet device to your static ip. Try ping, speedtest online.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. i bought domain. i forwarded it to my static ip. than i added below settings in rpi  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-local

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www
ServerName myuniquename.com
ServerAlias www.myuniquename.com
</VirtualHost>
```

i changed wordpress site&wordpress adress url to my domain. than i configured hosts file(c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) on my desktop.

```
192.168.1.31    myuniquename.com
192.168.1.31    www.myuniquename.com
```